# OpenCV4android - No implementation found for long org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.CvSVM_0()

Tags: android, android-studio, opencv, android-ndk

Здравствуйте. Пишу проект на Андроид в связке с OpenCV. В определенный момент, когда я пытаюсь создать объект классификатора SVM:

```
CvSVM svmModel = new CvSVM();
```

У меня появляется вот эта ошибка:

```
04-13 15:49:56.794  21020-21020/victorovich_d.signer_1_static E/art﹕ No implementation found for long org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.CvSVM_0() (tried Java_org_opencv_ml_CvSVM_CvSVM_10 and Java_org_opencv_ml_CvSVM_CvSVM_10__)
04-13 15:49:56.796  21020-21020/victorovich_d.signer_1_static E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: victorovich_d.signer_1_static, PID: 21020
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.CvSVM_0() (tried Java_org_opencv_ml_CvSVM_CvSVM_10 and Java_org_opencv_ml_CvSVM_CvSVM_10__)
        at org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.CvSVM_0(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.<init>(CvSVM.java:63)
        at victorovich_d.signer_1_static.SvmCore.<init>(SvmCore.java:18)
        at victorovich_d.signer_1_static.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:28)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1085)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2385)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2544)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:150)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1394)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:168)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5845)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:797)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:687)
04-13 15:50:02.511  21020-21029/victorovich_d.signer_1_static E/art﹕ No implementation found for void org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.delete(long) (tried Java_org_opencv_ml_CvSVM_delete and Java_org_opencv_ml_CvSVM_delete__J)
04-13 15:50:02.511  21020-21029/victorovich_d.signer_1_static E/System﹕ Uncaught exception thrown by finalizer
04-13 15:50:02.512  21020-21029/victorovich_d.signer_1_static E/System﹕ java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.delete(long) (tried Java_org_opencv_ml_CvSVM_delete and Java_org_opencv_ml_CvSVM_delete__J)
        at org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.delete(Native Method)
        at org.opencv.ml.CvSVM.finalize(CvSVM.java:413)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:210)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:193)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Которая ведет к библиотечной функции:

```
public   CvSVM()
{
    super( CvSVM_0() );

    return;
}
```

Долго и упорно гуглив я начал понимать что проблема в подключении библиотек, но как конкретно решить проблему я не понял. Буду рад любой помощи. Могу выложить исходники некотрых файлов по надобности. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я нашел библиотеку которой нехватало и возможно помогу тому кто столкнется с подобной проблемой в OpenCV, с  этой проблемой можно столкнуться не только при использовании SVM, а так-же при использовании всех функций которые требуют эту jni библиотеку. Например:

```
Mat myMat = new Mat();
```

Для решения этой проблемы необходимо добавить вот эту строку кода в Main класс:

```
static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); }
```